# Query on CORBA standard

Tags: sockets, corba

If i make sure that kernel on client & server machine uses

```
1. same protocol stack for instance AF_INET(say) 
2. use same delivery mechanism for instance SOCK_STREAM(say)
```

then

1)

Don't you think you can write a client program in Java(On Windows) and Server program in C(On Solaris)?

2)

Is yes, Why do we need CORBA standard for client-server communication between software components in different languages for different OS running on different architectures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Don't you think you can write a client program in Java(On Windows) and Server program in C(On Solaris)?

Of course you can.

> Why do we need CORBA standard for client-server communication between software components in different languages for different OS running on different architectures?

Because it's an instance of what you describe, and because it provides about a million facilities that you would otherwise have to code yourself every time you required them.

Comment: Can you name on important facilities that it provides?

Comment: A naming service; a persistence service; location-independence; failover, in some implementations; a hardware-independent protocol; interceptors; portable object adapters; dynamic servants; ... There's an enormous shopping-list. You should also note that CORBA ORBs are the basis of most J2EE server implementations. There's nothing trivial about it that just equates to a couple of sockets.

Comment: Binary marshaling, ability to not do any marshaling when client/server are in the same process, compression support, threading, queueing, policies, real time capabilities, and much more

Comment: jonnywillemsen  compression suport of idl objects, threading at skeleton side for serving the request, queuing at skeleton side am i correct?

Comment: @sham A million things. Let's not try to list them all here please. The documentation does exist.

Comment: @EJP Can you provide any good link for that documentation which talks about facilities that CORBA provides? Because most of the documents talk about language/platform independence.